# mySQL: I need to input a decimal into an int column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, integer, decimal

I have a table with a current structure as follows:

[image]

Currently this is populated as follows:

[image]

The data stored for product value is a decimal value
and the end digits are cut off once it is inserted into the database.

I have tried changing the table structure as follows:

[image]

However this only leads to the following:

[image]

As you can see all values have a `.00` appended if none exists, however I want to 
store all these values with no decimal places. Except the product value.

How can I do this?

Comment: your confusing storage and formatting issues, store the correct value, and format(display) it any way you like.

Comment: have you tried outputValue(18,0)?

Comment: But if I select a value from the database and want to output it to the screen without the `.00` will I not need to apply a `round()` function each time?

Comment: So do you mean if I stick to the int stucture, the correct value is still stored only I can't see it until extracted and outputted?

Comment: you will need to check if there is a decimal and you will need to use `round()` or `floor()` or `sprintf()` to format your number. there is no way around, this is normal. you might try the datatype `FLOAT` if you dont like it.

Comment: OK, thanks I was aware I might have to do this but just wanted to avoid rounding by simply inputting the data as it is needed.

Comment: you want to avoid doing it 'properly' ? why?

Comment: I'm a newbie, I don't know what properly is!!

Comment: So how do I close this question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is you are converting a decimal (float / double) to an integer, so the value is simply truncated (decimal values are chopped off).

If you really don't want to use floats (decimal values) in the database you can use this hack work around will work:

Multiply the number by 100 before inserting it, and then be sure to divide it by 100 when you use the data. This will allow you to maintain 2 decimal points while using integer storage.

Thus, 2.4 would be stored as 240, 53 would be 5300, 20.74 becomes 2074 etc...

I want to note that this is not an ideal solution, but rather a hack.

I highly recommend what the other users suggested in the comments: storing the decimal value (as you have) and formatting it when presenting it.

--- In addition ---

Your real problem appears to be with the way the database is setup.

Each of those values should have their own field since they will be repeated for each product.